# Apple keyboard on Windows PC: will CMD buttons work as CTRL?

Tags: keyboard, windows

I use mac at home, but at work I have to use Win7 PC. It makes me crazy to switch between mac/win keybard everyday, so I want to buy mac usb keyboard, but, **will CMD buttons work as CTRL in windows** 'out of the box'?
I can use some mapping software, but it would be much better just to plug it in and use.

Comment: I would use the mapping software. On the mac. **Karabiner** is the most flexible.

Comment: i know, but the thing is, I preffer mac keyboard over Windows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. The difference is not a Mac vs Win keyboard. You can use a Windows keyboard on a Mac and the keys are the same.

The difference in in the OS. Windows treats ctrl-C as copy and OS X cmd-C. They just differ and I know of not way of mapping them

Comment: I know it is OS issue, but I thought maybe Win maps cmd as ctrl on apple keyboard. AFAIK it is possible to remap buttons except Win key, can you tell me how Win registers pressing cmd button?

Comment: The cmd button is alt or alt-gr on a Windows keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Command button will act as Windows button, Control as Ctrl, Option as Alt. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202676 section "How Microsoft Windows Function keys are mapped to Apple keyboards".

Answer (score 0):

I am 95% certain the answer is NO, but I do not have a Windows PC to verify.

Comment: It should work as Windows key. ctrl (⌃) should be equivalent of Control on Win.